# update *ngFor with ChangeDetectorRef

Tags: angular, angular2-services, ngfor, angular-changedetection

I've got a little problem and one of these days where I can't seem to find a good solution for it. I tried some solutions from similar questions but without success.

When the user is logged out, all links are disabled. Once the user the logged in, some links should only be disabled, when the user does not have the role `Admin`.

I have read most of the similar questions and came up with the `EventEmitterService` to call a method in the `app.component.ts` from the `login.component.ts`. The called method in `app.component.ts` calls `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.

However, the links are still disabled, although the user logged in has the role `Admin`.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  navLinks = [
    { path: 'hello', label: 'Hello' },
    { path: 'administration', label: 'Administration', role: 'admin' }
  ];

  private roles: string[];
  isAdmin = false;

  constructor(
    ...
    private eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.eventEmitterService.subsVar === undefined) {
      this.eventEmitterService.subsVar = this.eventEmitterService.
      invokeRoleRefreshFunction.subscribe((name: string) => {
        this.updateRoles();
      });
    }
    ...
  }

  updateRoles() {
    const user = this.tokenStorageService.getUser();

    this.roles = user.roles;
    console.log(this.roles);

    this.isAdmin = this.roles.includes('ROLE_ADMIN');

    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link
     *ngFor="let link of navLinks"
     [disabled]="link.role === 'admin' && !isAdmin || !isLoggedIn"
     [routerLink]="link.path"
     routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
     [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
     [active]="rla.isActive">
    {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private eventEmitterService: EventEmitterService) { }

  onLogin() {
    ...
    this.eventEmitterService.onLogin();
  }
}
```

Sorry for missing StackBlitz. Hope someone can give me a hint.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with your setup regarding the Change detector ref, but I do see an issue with the condition for disabled. Your check for !isAdmin || !isLoggedIn should be wrapped in (). I also think both of these booleans shouldnt have NOT since I think you are intending for the user to be logged in to enable the link, which also means OR should change to AND.

Comment: First I would like to say, you need an [Authentication Guard](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) (route guard) in your routes, then you wouldn't need to check if the user is logged-in in every component. second `link.role === 'admin'` should be `link?.role === 'admin'` as not all links have a role and the disabled flag should be `!isLoggedIn && !isAdmin && link?.role === 'admin'`. Also I'd like to add that your disabled flag should be a pipe tho.

Comment: Apologies, the above comment from Bargos looks correct, had the ! condition mixed up in my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I changed my my disabled flag to !isLoggedIn && !isAdmin && link?.role === 'admin'. Also thanks for the hint regarding Authentication Guard and on using a pipe for my flag. I will definitely look into it. However, the links are still disabled. But when I refresh the page manually or programmatically the links are enabled. Any guess?